# Visual studio: How to use release mode properly

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to release my program as a *release* build. I switched to release mode and then my *.h file broke.

```
#include "GL\glew.h"
#include "GLFW\glfw3.h"
#include "ft2build.h"
#include "FTGL\ftgl.h"

//#include "GL/glew.h"  
//#include <GLFW/glfw3.h> 
//#include <ft2build.h>
//#include <FTGL/ftgl.h>
```

The above I have included. Both sets result in the following error:

> 1>C:\Users\student\Documents\VSTest\hw2_hci\Release\hw2_hci.exe :
>   fatal error LNK1120: 33 unresolved externals

Now I come from a Java background, which is extremely easy to understand.

If I was to go for a a release version, where should my dll and other libraries (such as ftgl or glfw) be located, so that when I try this program out on any windows 7 machine it will work (excluding the c++ updates required etc. by the os).

Comment: use the Properties dialog to set up your include path, library path, etc.  You need to do this for both Debug and Release build.  There is also an All Configurations you can select to make changes to both Debug and Release build configurations.

Comment: @RichardChambers Actually, it's a lot easier to just edit the `.vcxproj` file using your usual editor than to try and do this for all of the possible build types.

Comment: Compare Linker settings in Debug and Release configurations. Specifically, Additional dependencies list.

Comment: The correction you made to the header is wrong. It's invalid C++ (in two ways: single backslashes, and using backslash in an include directive), although accepted by Visual C++ as a language extension. Remove the new includes and uncomment the old.

Comment: Perfect information people! I didn't know that both debug and release had different configurations!

Comment: @Alf It's not invalid.  In an include directive, the sequence in quotes is a _q-char-sequence_, not a string literal.  Pretty much everything concerning its interpretation is implementation defined, and there's certainly no requirement that the implementation recognize escape sequences for string literals.

Comment: @JamesKanze, it is easier if you know what you are doing.  The Properties dialog is easier and less confusing for someone who does not.

Comment: @RichardChambers The Properties dialog leads to exactly the type of issues presented here: you have to maintain multiple copies of the data.  If you look in the `.vcxproj` file, you'll see a long list of conditional sections, all with exactly the same thing.  (Or not, if you've forgotten something somewhere.)  It's really pretty simple to get rid of the condition, and put what you want in the single remaining entry.  And if you have multiple projects, it is definitely preferable to include a `.props` file with all of the compiler options, in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Unresolved externals are quite a simple thing if you understand how linking works. I am not going into details here, but assuming that your linkage works when you are in Debug mode, but not in Release, it can mean two possible things:

a) Every project configuration (Release/Debug) has to be configured separately in terms of included libraries (unless you are using properly configured property sheets). So first, switch your solution to be in Release and then look at your project settings -> Linker -> Input-> Additional Dependencies. You must be sure that the OpenGL and FTGL libraries are present there. When you added them in Debug, it doesn't mean they are added in Release, you have to do it there again.

b) Some libraries come in two flavours, one with a `*d` Suffix, and some without (like `MyLibd.lib` and `MyLib.lib`). The one with the d-suffix is the debug variant where some functions *might* have different symbols. Make sure that you add the d-suffix libraries in your Debug, and the one without the suffix in your Release configuration.

The problem itself means that some functions could not be found by the linker. Looking through the specific linker errors you might see the name of the function that is missing, mostly somewhat obfuscated (called "name mangeling") like this:

`unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl MyFunction(int,int)" (?MyFunction@@YAXHH@Z) referenced in function _main`

This means that `MyFunction` could not be resolved, and you have to make sure that you import the proper import-library of the DLL that contains this function.

EDIT: As AndreyT suggested, it is a very good idea to select the "All Configurations" setting from the drop down menu within the project settings dialog when you are doing changes to the project settings and want them to be in every configuration. This saves you the trouble of re-doing the same things for every configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Each configuration of the project uses its own independent set of settings.

Your program apparently uses some external libraries. You added these libraries to Linker settings of the Debug configuration of your project. But you never added them to Linker settings of Release configuration. Hence the errors.

Go to project settings, inspect all settings that are supposed to be invariant between Debug and Release builds and make sure they are in-sync. In this case that would be `Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies`.

In the future, when you are changing project setting that are not specific to a particular configuration (like Debug or Release build), make sure you always select "All configurations" in the settings dialog before entering the new values.